# Use updated version of Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, installation

I have Python 3.4 installed on my Linux computer.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4
```

However, when I run `python -V`, it shows that Python 2.7.6 is being used.

How do I tell the system to use the updated version of Python?

The answer to this question for a windows computer is at [How to update version of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089939/how-to-update-version-of-python), but I couldn't find an answer for Linux.

Comment: Specify the new executable: `python3.4 -V`

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, installations of python3 installed by the package manager (e.g. apt) can be called as `python3`.  You might need to specify the version - e.g.  `python3.5` if the package manager has installed more than one, or you've compiled your own installations from source.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the version in the shebang.
write `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

when run via `./my_script.py` it will run in python3.

otherwise run it via `python3 my_script.py`.

if you just want to start an interactive python shell start it with `python3`

you also can be more specific with the version. just replace `python3` with `python3.4` (if installed)

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu various python executable are places under `/usr/bin/` and might look like

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3.2
/usr/bin/python3.4
```

etc. so when you execute a command `python -v` it looks for a file with that name in that location. so to choose your version specify it like `python3.4 -v`

you can replace the simlink `/usr/lib/python` with `/usr/bin/python3.4` to make that "default"